# Merge [facebook-<X>] into [facebook]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

- [[facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)]: 138
- [[facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages)]: 8
- [[facebook-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-chat)]: 5
- [[facebook-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-apps)]: 4
- [[facebook-connect](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-connect)]: 3
- [[facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games)]: 3
- [[facebook-alternative](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-alternative)]: 2
- [[facebook-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-account)]: 1
- [[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups)]: 1

Could these be merged into [facebook] ?
Just a suggestion, I would do it by hand but I wanted to know what others thought.

Answer (score 3):

I think (most of them|they) should be.

While I feel that a myriad of tags is useful for some larger sites - Google in particular, where each tag usually refers to a separate app which comes under the Google brand - I don't think that the majority of these Facebook tags are really useful, since they come under the singular Facebook application - while Google Docs and Gmail are two distinct applications, Facebook pages and Facebook groups are a small part of a much bigger app.

One tag of note (possible saving), however, is [facebook-connect] - since it can be used as a method of authentication for sites other than Facebook.

Comment: Wow, re-reading though that I think I abused the English language a little.

Answer (score 1):

I think `[facebook-alternative]`, `[facebook-games]`, `[facebook-account]` can definitely be merged.

The rest can probably be merged too, but those are the obvious ones.