# When [facebook-games], when [facebook][facebook-games], when [facebook] [games], or what?

Tags: support, tags

UPDATE: Since [games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) has been burninated much of this Q has become moot so acceptance of the existing A closes this version for me. More [here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/burninate-limit) though.

---

Q When is [facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games) appropriate, on its own (~0 uses), as opposed to either [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games)<sup>†</sup> (~2 uses) or [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games) (~5 uses) or one or more other tags instead?

Apparently [facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games), along with several others, has in the past been merged into [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) ([Merge [facebook-] into [facebook]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/494/merge-facebook-x-into-facebook)).

There have been [comments](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/clean-up-needed-of-meta-tag-archive), such as (referring to [archive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive)):

> This tag can't stand alone as the only tag on a question; it would always need another tag to give context. This seems to me to be a classic Meta tag.

which hark back to one of Jeff’s [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)s where he wrote:

> **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

though the (extreme) examples he gave were [beginner](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner), [subjective](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) and [best-practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) ([data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) may be [another](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4291/please-blacklist-tag-data)), which to me seem far removed from the likes of [archive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive) or [games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games).

It seems that if a tag can “stand on its own” the chances are most Qs should only even have a single tag (maybe like [facebook-friend-request-messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-friend-request-messages)?) – or the Q is likely to be “too broad” (for covering more than a single topic) anyway.

Considering [documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documents) that was the topic of [Merging [doc], [document] and [documents] tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/merging-doc-document-and-documents-tags). It can mean different things to different people (eg Word, PDF, a file in Google Documents, evidence for account recovery such as driving licence or passport (or *images* thereof, etc) and not so far actually applied in isolation (for a very small sample).

Related Q but inconclusive: [Why are more general tags getting removed from questions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/why-are-more-general-tags-getting-removed-from-questions)

Also related but not conclusive: [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/in-the-context-of-web-applications-which-are-the-tags-that-are-not-specific-to)

<sup>†</sup> May only be temporary, but [games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) does not exist at the moment (though it did when this Q was asked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) seems awfully close to a meta-tag for me. Sure there may be some web applications that are games, but someone coming here looking for questions to answer isn't going to be looking for "games" questions; no one is going to be an "expert" on all web app games.

A quick glance at the questions in there bear that out. Just in the first few results I see questions about:

- GameFAQs, which probably doesn't count as a web app
- a generic browser game
- Google+ games
- Facebook games
- developing a language learning app as a game
- a request for a recommendation for a recommendation engine
- VM hosting
- request for recommendation of sports standings
- request for recommendation for web-based arcade games
- request for recommendation for dice-rolling apps

None of them have any real context without another tag to go along.

Personally, I'd prefer simply [facebook-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-apps) to generically cover all Facebook applications, including games, but I can see the argument for [facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games) as places like the Google Play store segregate out games from "regular" apps.

---

I think [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games) is okay, as either one describes the topic of the question; one's just more specific than the other. Someone qualified to answer a Facebook question is almost certainly going to be able to answer something about a Facebook game.

Comment: Same. "Notifications" is too generic, especially when [tag:facebook-notifications] already exists.

Comment: Probably not. "Games" seems more clear-cut to me.