# Burninate [limit]?

Tags: discussion, tag-clean-up

I draw your attention to the [limit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit) tag. This seems to be a perfect definition of a meta tag.

It's currently on 43 questions. The tag excerpt reads:

> For questions where upper or lower restrictions are core issues. Examples would include minimum age for viewing and maxima for rate of sending emails, free storage capacity, number of followers, API calls in a given time, video quality, etc.

I see it on a variety of questions for a broad range of web applications, with any number of uses of "limit". Some examples:

- the possible limit to the number of pages in a Google Doc
- how to restrict the number of posts you're seeing from people you follow on Twitter
- recovering contacts in Google Hangouts (with the tangential question of whether there is a limit to the number)
- the maximum number of items in a Cognito Forms picklist
- if there is a limit to the number columns in a Google Sheet

...and many more.

No one is an "expert" in "limits" who would come here looking for questions to answer.

Based on [Shog9's criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/21960):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Only insofar as web apps sometimes limit things.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Definitely no.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Certainly not. It's used as a noun as well as a verb, and often as a synonym for "restrict" and "filter".

It should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag has been removed from all questions and the tag wiki has been removed.